# Javascript element position relative to screen

Tags: javascript, html, browser, position

I need get position of an element relative to the screen or to the top left point of the window (point (window.screenX, window.screenY).

Why? I need desktop application to draw something on this position. I am able to get rect of the whole window and document, but I can't get the offset between top of the window and the top of the document.

Using `window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight` doesn't work, if user has opened, for example, debugging console of the browser.

Any thoughts? There are some articles about it on SP, but all of them works for me as relative to the document's view port.

Edit: other possible solution would be, to get screenX/Y values of the document

Thanks

Comment: Seems like you might want jQuery `.offset()` - also see http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#offset

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking around for the same thing, and surprisingly, this is tricky to implement.

There is a Firefox only solution -- `window.mozInnerScreenX` and `window.mozInnerScreenY` will give you the left and top of the viewport relative to the screen.

For other browsers, as far as I can tell, you'll need to listen to the first mouse or touch event. These events contain both screen and client coordinates of the event, which can be used to calculate the screen coordinates of the viewport.

```
innerScreenX = event.screenX - event.clientX;
innerScreenY = event.screenY - event.clientY;
```

Note that screen coordinates can be unexpected values (like -ve values) in case of multi monitor setups.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to using a plugin jquery has the .position() method so you can do for the doc

**UPDATED** Solution

```
// get element position relative to the document
var pos = $("#element").position();
var elePosX = pos.left;
var elePosY = pos.top;

// get window position relative to screen
var winPosX = window.screenX;
var winPosY = window.screenY;

// calculate the height of the navigation/toolbar
var navHeight = window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;

// absolute x relative to the screens top left is the
//windows x position + the elements x position
var absX = winPosX + elePosX;

// absolute y relative to the screens top left is the
// windows y position + the height of the nav bar + the
// elements y position
var absY = winPosY + navHeight + elePosY;

// output values
console.log({"x": absX, "y": absY});
```

Comment: .position() doesn't return position relative to (window.screenX, window.screenY) point

Comment: please see my updated solution with comments. this was tested in firefox.

Comment: `window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;` doesn't work if user opens e.g. a debug console, because `innerHeight` is in this case reduced from both top and bottom.

Comment: outerHeight - innerHeight + screenY gives the offset relative to physical screen coordinates in Chrome.  Very helpful.

Answer (score -2):

you may want to look into the following properties of window ...

[window.screen.top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen.top) - Returns the distance in pixels from the top side of the current screen.
[windows.screen.left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.screen.left) - Returns the distance in pixels from the left side of the main screen to the left side of the current screen.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking for something more browser independent.